# Video Concatenation or Merging

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, ffmpeg

I need to **join/merge/concatenate** more than two different video files (Eg :3gp, mp4 ) in android platform **and need to store them as mp4 file.**

So far from my analysis, I’ve seen people referring FFMPEG for these purposes.

Is **FFMPEG** available for android? Or any other alternative packages available for video concatenation ?

Can FFMPEG concatenate two different kinds of Video files?(Eg: **Combination** of mp4 and 3gp)

Update: Can **OpenGL** be helpful for merging more than two videos along with audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least this project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/.

See the [FFmpeg FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files) about video (and audio) concatenation. You can even join files that use different codecs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope ffmpeg handles audios as well?. Is there any other better alternative for FFMPEG?

Comment: @2vision2: Define "better". The answer to your question depends on what your most important criterion is.

Comment: Sorry for my comment if anything wrong with it. Many people might have already tried different solutions for video Concatenation. Each package may have its own pro's and con's. If someone helps me to know other possible options(Eg:OpenGL or x or Y), i can just have a study on it.

Comment: @2vision2 Yes, FFmpeg can handle audio, too, as well as files with different codecs (see the FAQ page I linked).